# json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In this code when you click on button a screenshot should be taken and screenshot should be shown by updating useState, but i get this error:
*json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures*
how can i solve this?

```
let [ImageURI, setImageURI,]=useState(<Image source={{uri:'http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg'}}/>);
```

Here the function is that we use for taking screenshot and updating useState:

```
const captureScreenFunction=()=>{

    captureScreen({
        format: "jpg",
        quality: 0.8
      }).then(
        uri => setImageURI(ImageURI=uri),
        error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
      );

}
```

And here what is returns:

```
    return (


 <Fragment>

<Button
title='capture screen'
onPress={captureScreenFunction}

>
</Button>

<Image
source={{uri:ImageURI}}
style={{width:300, height:200, resizeMode:'contain', marginTop:15}}
></Image>

</Fragment>


    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course it is cyclic, because you use `Image` in the definition of `Image` itself:

```js
<Image
  source={{uri:ImageURI}}
  style={{width:300, height:200, resizeMode:'contain', marginTop:15}}
></Image>
```

`ImageURI`, here, I assume, refers to `ImageURI` constructed in the hook definition:

```
let [ImageURI, setImageURI,]=useState(<Image source={{uri:'http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg'}}/>);
```

I think the fix is easy, and also better, because state variables should be as simple as possible:

```
let [ImageURI, setImageURI,] = useState('http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg');
```

That's also consistent with the data type you are setting it to later in your code (a string).